# How to prevent Twig from replacing single quote by double quote in HTML tag attribute?

Tags: twig

Using Twig in Symfony 5, it appear that declarations in template like this :

```
<input type='text' value='hello' />
```

are automatically replaced by

```
<input type="text" value="hello" />
```

I'm using a JS library (Yaireo Tagify) which can automatically populate an input with json object (so with quotes), that implies using single quote in the input attribute. See discussion here : https://github.com/yairEO/tagify/issues/597

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: How did you verify this? Did you use the developer tools from your browser? This will give you an "incorrect" output of the source. Try verifying with pressing `CTRL + U`. Twig won't change your single quotes to double quotes (by default). See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/vq2gr5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevTools give an incorrect view of output source...
Twig won't change single quotes to double quotes